# Using Swashbuckle to document model properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

It's pretty easy to get swashbuckle to generate the descriptions individual parameters passed into operations but if I pass in a model like this:

```
public void Put([FromUri] ViewModelTest viewModelTest)
{
}
```

And the Model looks like this:

```
public class ViewModelTest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a recommended strategy for populating the descriptions for the model?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example:
http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index#!/TestEnum/TestEnum_Put

[image]

And the code is on GitHub:
https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/blob/master/Swagger_Test/Models/ViewModelTest.cs

```
public class ViewModelTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The super ID that will be used
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>123</example>
    public int SuperId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Who needs a name?
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>John Doe</example>
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

...And in your Swagger config (App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs)  you will need to enable IncludeXmlComments

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that example just passes a single parameter, and as mentioned above, it's fairly easy to document this with xml comments above the controller action. What I want to be able to do is document the fields of a Model (POCO) that's passed in.

Comment: And here is how your model looks like with the xml comments:
http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index#!/TestEnum/TestEnum_Put

Comment: And the most important page is missing: https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/blob/master/Swagger_Test/Models/ViewModelTest.cs

Comment: In the working example, the request URL comes back like so `http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/api/TestEnum/1?viewModelTest.id=123&viewModelTest.name=Jim` but is there a way to not use the model name on each parameter? So you could essentially use a URL like this `http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/api/TestEnum/1?id=123&name=Jim`

Comment: Followup: I found my answer here: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/issues/515
 . Basically have to tell it to use the unqualified form `[FromUri(Name = "")]`